# Is there a way to instantiate an instance of a constrained generic type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, instance

I'm coming to you because I've exhausted all of the Google recommendations. I'm trying to create a websocket system that will handle statically typed requests and responses.

I'm generating the request/response types from another project. I have two base types (`RequestData` and `ResponseData`) and a "GenericRequest" that the user will interact with when trying to send new requests. An example looks like this:

```
export class RequestData {}
export class ResponseData {}

export class GenericRequest<T extends RequestData, V extends ResponseData> {}
```

```
interface HandshakeResponseData extends ResponseData {
    AuthCode: string;
    RequestId: number; //unsigned
    RedirectUrl: string;
}

interface HandshakeRequestData extends RequestData {
    AuthCode: string;
    RequestId: number; //unsigned
    SessionToken: string;
}

export class HandshakeRequest extends GenericRequest<HandshakeRequestData, HandshakeResponseData> {}
```

Here is an example of it's usage.

```
new HandshakeRequest({
    AuthCode: "0",
    SessionToken: "<jwt>"
}).send(socket).then((data) => {
    // response handler logic
});
```

There is a function within `GenericRequest<T,V>` called `send()` that sends a request off and waits for a response. When the response comes back, it is supposed to convert the response json into a `ResponseData` instance of type `V`. I'm having trouble creating the new instance of ResponseData from the generic argument `V`:

```
private create<R> (type: { new(): R} ) : R {
        return new type();
}
```

^ This is the method of instantiating a generic type I've seen all over Stack Overflow, but it doesn't seem to work for me when I do this:

```
foo() : V { // where V corresponds to generic argument of GenericRequest<T,V>
    return this.create<V>(V);
}
```

I get an error on the parameter within the parenthesis:

`'V' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. ts(2693)`

Here is the most minimum reproducible sample I could think of. I'd like to instantiate a new `V` object where `V` in `Foo<V>`

```
class Foo<V> {
    constructor() {

    }

    create<V>(type: { new(): V} ) : V {
        return new type();
    }

    thisIsTheError() {
        let bar: V = this.create<V>(V);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit this code into a [mcve] that can be dropped into any standalone IDE (like [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)) and where the only issues present are the ones you are facing. Right now I get errors unrelated to your issue. Without that I can only speak generally: write the runtime code and then come up with types for it. At runtime, `this.create()` presumably needs a constructor of the `V` type passed into it.  The `GenericRequest` constructor should take a value of this type, so you have it on hand when you call `create()` later. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I have updated my question with a sample at the bottom :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when the code is transpiled into Javacript.  At runtime, you can't call `this.create(V)` or `new V` because `V` does not exist.  (That's what the error is telling you).  The solution you see elsewhere about requiring a parameter of type `new()=>V` is meant to indicate that, at runtime, you need an actual constructor object that makes instances of type `V`.  Such a constructor object doesn't come into existence magically; anything that needs one of those will have to get it from somewhere.  In your small `Foo` example, I'd say it should be passed into the `Foo` constructor, like this:

```
class Foo<V> {

  // pass in the V constructor here:
  constructor(private ctor: new () => V) {

  }

  create<V>(type: { new(): V }): V {
    return new type();
  }

  thisIsTheError() {
    let bar: V = this.create(this.ctor); // okay now
    return bar; // return this just to show what it does
  }
}
```

Of course that means you can't just call `new Foo()` anymore.

```
const badFoo = new Foo(); // error, needs an argument
```

You'll need to pass it a no-arg constructor of the type you want your `Foo` to make.  For example:

```
class Baz {
  constructor(public name: string = "Fred") { }
  yell() {
    console.log("HEY MY NAME IS " + this.name.toUpperCase() + "!!!")
  }
}

const foo = new Foo(Baz); 
const baz = foo.thisIsTheError(); // okay, type is Baz
baz.yell(); // HEY MY NAME IS FRED!!!
```

You can see that `foo` is inferred to be of type `Foo<Baz>` since you pass it the no-arg `Baz` constructor.  (`Baz` does allow you to `new` it with no arguments... the `name` property will become the default value `"Fred"`).  And then `foo.thisIsTheError()` successfully instantiates the `Baz` class by calling its constructor with no argument.  I made `thisIstheError()` return the `bar` value so you could see that it really is a class instance, and has the `yell()` method.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8A1AfNA3gWAFDWmHgDsIAXAJwFdgz4KAKABwoEsA3MMgU0LooBc0YtwDu0BgEpoAXgwppOXHgIBfPCsIVuXbqjQMyATybchmYWKlCU0VZJtZNBbWSoVil8cdNSA3JrqyvjQZAAWrBAAkhAAKmHcAKIUFPRSTiEEINxk0ABGYILQtjKhERAAdMDauoblVfySAZnQru6eBRR+0AD0Pa057WWR0ABWVOSh8NAQYfDiomFc0Ky5ACbw3BCBeEEauESkuQVrCNOlIuJn-r393Cn0ADSW3GswYJ6FAOZUALbcxDI+1AkBgACEwAAvDIEQ7kai0NJMKh5ECsYDCMD-ITw1jEL6yaAAIlg2jWRMUdk0Rm4IBA6SUBFhJAg8GyFRA8C+DCJAAlEgBNaAAWSFADkAILCxLQKIAZWJ0AA1MNKsQsdwKnQAKpMUwUADCkG46RVRIAhJaKTtcHsDizcgAzRCEy5wRAMCGQprQPBw45QwnO+Ba8oxeJJB6MH19aDwADWYCMzx8vBGXrwBUhFRpdJusf5QtF0El0tlCtgACVEgARS3m-Z4IA)