# Typescript: Using nested generic class type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use a nested class type generic.
Let's say I have the following code:

```
class Base {
  property: string|undefined;
} 

class A extends Base {
  aProperty: string | undefined;
}

class B extends Base {
  aProperty: string | undefined;
}

function createFunc<T extends Base>(c: new () => T): T {
  return new c();
}

class GenericClass<T extends Base> {
  constructor() {
    // This doesn't work. But why?
    const typeProperty = createFunc(T);
  }
}
// This works however. Not using the nested generic
createFunc(Base)
```

[Typescript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1oAcBOB7TC2ALgJ4Bc0ER2AlgHYDmAPgK50AmCAZvQuwNyoAvtFSpQkGAEFoCAB5EEHGPAhI0GMAAU8BYuUrV6DaE2htOPOn0FCxEqHFkKl7FYhTpo23YVIUqWkZTcw5uXgFhMS42YCIaXDpoYGwEMEUAMViAHgAVZ0VlOEQAPgAKYAprAHdoMoBKaABeEuhc%20op8jWhUohZsJJrkhtt7cEcAcSVCGmAAYXGIPILXdzVW7uBEwJY43GwGzwwMAHoTtoALGhh2XAQIOgByImhq-YBrADo4Fhfqi5IAH4vBgtnQqNBSAQdPg-CRmslUukEFk6MAyu1BBg7HYzpdrq8PjALrhqggAG6EaB0XAvFgQYyQi5IaxUPjQBjTWjAcRIzKxMqqBD1IA)

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? Is this a bug or intended behaviour and what would be a workaround?

I read about it here but it doesn't really explain why this shouldn't work.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics

Comment: T has no runtime existence.

Comment: You say "this doesn't work" but you're not describing the error, which is important in a [mre].  The error is `'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`  If you look up that error you'll find questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599052/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-an-instance-of-a-constrained-generic-type-in-types, and the recommended solution is to pass a class constructor, not a type, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjk47N).  Does this meet your needs or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry thought linking the typescript playground was enough. Looking at the compiled javascript I understand why it doesn't work thanks to @Matthieu

Comment: @jcalz What I want specifically is to create an instance of a type that is passed in a generic of a class. I don't want/can't pass the constructor in the classes constructor. However I don't think that's really possible with generics alone.

Comment: Right, it's not possible.  Your `GenericClass` will compile to something like `class GenericClass{  constructor() {  const typeProperty = createFunc(T);  }` and that `T` doesn't refer to anything.  So why don't you want to pass in the constructor?  You have to pass in *some* value.  I'm trying to figure out what kind of answer to post or link to if any.  It could just be "you can't do this, sorry".  Is that what you want to see?

Comment: I mean the answer I would have wanted to see was an explanation of why it doesn't work. I can't use the constructor because the class is never constructed manually and the constructer can't have parameters.  My work around is assigning a property that holds the constructer when I use the class. Which is a bit bad but it beats having to reextend the class for every generic I intend to use it on. BUT that was never what I was asking about I was more just looking for a "this doesn't work because of these reasons"